# Intuition behind the horizontal factor in a sinusoidal function

Tags: trigonometry, intuition, periodic-functions

**I came across the following question:**
[image]

**And here is an excerpt of its solution:**
[image]

---

I understand how the horizontal factor is calculated:

$period=\frac{2\pi}{horizontal factor}$

$365=\frac{2\pi}{horizontal factor}$

$horizontal factor = \frac{2\pi}{365}$

However, I don't understand its implication for/how it connects to the scenario described in the question.

Comment: One period of the example graph is 365 days, however, since the period of $\sin(x)$ is only $2\pi$, you need to stretch out the basic sine wave and transform it to replicate the ""shape" of the sine wave in the example graph.

Comment: Since the graph shows the number of hours of daylight, and the assumption is that this cycles annually, you need a function with a period of 365, so the graph needs to be stretched accordingly.

Comment: @JC12 I believe that I understand that... What I don't understand is why the horizontal factor is $\frac{2\pi}{365}$, like what's the physical meaning of its "$2\pi$", its "365"?

Comment: @DMcMor My real confusion is restated in the above comment. Sorry for being unclear.